# How to send a next button, to a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to get a UITableView to show up after I tap a next button, I can't get it to work...

I don't know why TimesViewController.m isn't working, how do I link it...

```
-(IBAction)nextView:(UIBarButtonItem *) sender{

    [self pushViewController:TimesTableViewController.m animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: There is so much wrong with your code, I do not know where to begin. Read Apple's [View Controller Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read through [View Controller programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html). Essentially, it depends more on your application design. The most common ways of doing this are:

1. Tap on nextView should present TableView controller modally.
2. Tap on nextView should push TableView controller in the navigation stack.

With either of the approach, you need to create a separate view controller for your table view which will manage the table view and act as delegate/data source for it.

From within your button action handler you need to do it this way:

```
-(IBAction)nextView:(UIBarButtonItem *) sender{
    MyTableViewController *tableController = [[MyTableViewController alloc] init];

    // For #1 above
    [self presentViewController:tableController animated:YES completion:^{
        // Any code that you want to execute once modal presentation is done
    }];

    // For #2 above
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tableController animated:YES];
}
```

**EDIT:**

Create a initialize method on your MyTableViewController and pass the values while calling it.

```
- (id)initWithData1:(NSString *)iData1 data2:(NSString *)iData2 {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.data1 = iData1;
        self.data2 = iData2;
    }
    return self;
}

MyTableViewController *tableController = [[MyTableViewController alloc] initWithData1:@"Some String" data2:@"Another string"];
```

PS: You could also expose the string property in your header file of MyTableViewController and set it from the callee class

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly, I think the thing I didn't know to do, that I just figured out was to `#import` the `MyTableViewController.h` file. But thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: I think you removed your question in comments here. But I have already edited my answer to include that in. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

or if you wanna do it programmatically, in your viewDidLoad, after you created your button

```
[firstsessionButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showtable:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)showtable:(UIButton *)sender{
TableViewController *tableViewController=[[TableViewController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tableViewController animated:YES];
}
```